# Clean iOS Simulator / XCode

Tags: iphone, xcode

So I've been having trouble with laying out some things in IB.  I deleted my old .xib completely, and dropped in a new one.  To make sure everything was clean, all I did was add a label at the bottom.  I run my project, and it still runs the old project in the simulator to the last state of my .xib before I deleted it.  I tried the reset settings in the iOS simulator as well as cleaning my XCode project, and then rebuilding.  I still get the same .xib.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the app from the simulator and delete with finder the directory of your app in Library > Developer > Xcode > DerivedData.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've done most steps in the XCode voodoo dance:

1. Clean
2. Quit Xcode
3. Delete 'build' folder
4. Restart Xcode
5. Re-build

Give it a shot, with deleting the build folder.

Have you also checked that your new .xib is configured for the correct build target?

Comment: I tried steps 1-5 but it did not fix the issue.  How do I check the .xib is configured for the correct build target?

Comment: So after looking at both of the answers, neither worked right away.  I must have spent over an hour trying variations of these steps and eventually, some combination, of either cleaning twice, quitting xcode multiple times, did eventually work.  what a PIA!

Comment: That's why it's called the voodoo dance